# YouTube Video on Image Marker using QCAR SDK

Tags: android, video, image-processing, augmented-reality, qcar-sdk

I saw a question and answer posted previously on StackOverflow at this link

[Marker based AR android application using Qualcomm SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187248/marker-based-ar-android-application-using-qualcomm-sdk)

I’m trying to do something similar with the QCAR SDK. I am trying to display a YouTube video over the stones image. My base code is the images target file in the samples folder. I followed the steps mentioned here but I still get only the teapot to render over the image. Is there any other change I need to implement in the files?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the teapot rendering code from renderFrame() in ImageTargets.cpp.